# React Jest snapshots wait for re-render

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme, snapshot

I've just started working with Jest and I'm having some trouble understanding how to properly use Snapshots.

I'm currently trying to test [this component](https://codesandbox.io/s/github/coloredcat/navigation-drawer/tree/master/).

I've successfully managed to create a snapshot, but once I go check it out it looks like this:

```
// Jest Snapshot v1

exports[`>>>Sidemenu --- Snapshot +++capturing Snapshot of Sidemenu 1`] = `"<div class=\\"sc-dlnjPT eFWNyw\\">Test</div>"`;
```

I'm suspecting this is because my component's contents only show up on the second re-render, as they need a `width` value, this behavior is defined in [this file](https://codesandbox.io/s/github/coloredcat/navigation-drawer/tree/master/?file=/src/NavigationDrawer.js:1924-2204).

How would I tell Jest to wait for my component to re-render before creating the snapshot?

Will Enzyme even be able to get the window width value?

Answer (score 0):

For async operations the tricky is waiting for loading component, or something other thing that indicates that your component finished all re-renders and is ready to be snapshoted.

Something similar to this:

```
test('Page rendering test.', async () => {
    const pageRendering = renderer.create(<Page />);

    //  wait for your data to be loaded before you make your assertion.
    await waitForElementToBeRemoved(screen.getByText('Loading...'));

    expect(pageRendering.toJSON()).toMatchSnapshot();
});
```